# Include radio button for each row in PageblockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, pageblocktable, radio-button

I am having a hard time to figure out how I can include the radio button select option within the PageBlockTable. I am searching all the cases related to a contact here.

Logic in my controller extension which gets all the cases where contact name match:

```
public List<Case> excase{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> casesradio{get;set;}
public String radioValue{get;set;}
public Pagereference search() {
  excase = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Status, Subject from Case where contact.Name = : first + ' ' + last];
  for (Case cd: excase) {
   casesradio.add(new SelectOption(cd.Id, cd.Subject));
  }

  return null;
 }
```

I use PageblockTable tag to show it on the Page:

```
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!excase}" var="exscase" id="caselist">
       <apex:column value="{!exscase.CaseNumber}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!exscase.Status}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!exscase.Subject}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
```

I would also like user to select a particular case and update it.(My update has some logic which is irrelevant for this question). I use below code to show the cases as radio button selectOption:

```
    <apex:selectRadio label="Select Case to Update" value="{!radioValue}">
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!casesradio}"/>
    </apex:selectRadio>
```

This appears in a single line as shown in screenshot. My logic in extension for select option is(same as above):

```
public List<Case> excase{get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> casesradio{get;set;}
public String radioValue{get;set;}
public Pagereference search() {
  excase = [Select Id, CaseNumber, Status, Subject from Case where contact.Name = : first + ' ' + last];
  for (Case cd: excase) {
   casesradio.add(new SelectOption(cd.Id, cd.Subject));
  }

  return null;
 }
```

[image]

I am trying to get the radio button for each row in PagebLockTable as show in the screen shot. I would like to select the radio button and pass the selected case back to my extension when I click update. How can the code be modified to accomplish this.

Comment: This is a textbook use case for a wrapper class. A quick search of SFSE will give you lots of examples. Here's one from salesforce: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Comment: Is there any example where radio selectoption is used? If you see in my extension I am creating a list called caseradio. How can I use this as page blocktable value since page blocktable has already a value which displays list of cases.

Comment: Your pageblocktable will be bound to a list of the wrapper class (`cContact` in the linked example) instead of a list of `Case`. Each one of those wrappers will have a `Case` record "inside" it (`con` in the linked example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few days back I also have same problem. To resolve I use below steps:

1. I created an inner class in which I store the name (Label of Radio button).

   `class ContactName
   {
       String name;
   }`
2. Create a list of inner class and assign values to them.

   `List<ContactName> cName = new List<ContactName>();
    cName.add('This is a new case');
    cName.add('This is old Case');`
3. on VF Page, use html radio button tag in outputPanel

`<apex:pageBlockTable value="cName" var="cs">
     <apex:outputPanel>
         <input type="radio" name="caseName">
         <label>{!cs.name}</label>
     </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockTable>`

It will helps you.

Comment: Thanks. My pageblockTable has a value already from where I get list of Cases. public List<Case> excase{get;set;} , If I replace it with ContactName class then I would not be able to show Case in my table. I have read through the link given by Mark Pond above and It suggest to create a wrapper class. I did so and I was able to get the radio button for each cases, however there is an issue for which I posted a question. Can you assist me with that question?